# How to check if array is empty in handlebar templates?(ember js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have template, which contains simple icon template:

```
<span class="icon {{unbound pperson.medical.diseases '=' 0 'hidden'}}">    
            <img class="icon" src="/assets/img/icons/icon.svg                
</span>
```

As can be seen I need a flag to show/display it and I'm using `hidden` class for it. And I have data-array 'diseases'. So if it's empty I should not display icon, if it's not empty I should display this icon. I tried condition:

```
{unbound pperson.medical.diseases '=' 0 'hidden'}}
```

This gives error. I found that it was possible to write ember `handle bar` function and to use but I would like to find inline approach without creating aditional functions. is it possible?

Comment: have you tried `pperson.medical.diseases.length`?

Comment: @Anis I tried (pperson.medical.diseases.length '=' 0) and got: Assertion Failed: A helper named pperson.medical.diseases.length could not be found.

Comment: can you add a sandbox please, i can help but need to have some code to test solutions

Comment: @Anis thank you very much. after some experiments seems I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found solution. Probably on page load diseaseases didn't exist so I added null-undefined check. not it seems to be working

```
 <span class="icon {{unbound (unless (or null-undefined pperson.medical.disease pperson.medical.diseases.length '=' 0 ) 'hidden')}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ember considers an empty array as falsely. So you should be able to do this:

```
<span class="icon {{unless pperson.medical.diseases 'hidden'}}">    
  <img class="icon" src="/assets/img/icons/icon.svg                
</span>
```

Personally I feel that relying on the different truthiness of Handlebars templates compared to regular JavaScript makes the code more difficult to read. And Ember.js [may change](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/861) the template syntax to match JavaScript truthiness more closer. So I would recommend checking the length of the array instead. `0` is considered falsely just as in JavaScript.

```
<span class="icon {{unless pperson.medical.diseases.length 'hidden'}}">    
  <img class="icon" src="/assets/img/icons/icon.svg                
</span>
```

The [`{{unbound}}` helper](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.8/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/unbound?anchor=unbound) is only needed if you want to prevent your template reflecting changes in application state. `{{unbound pperson.medical.diseases}}` would cause the user interface *not* to change if items are added or removed from diseases array. This is nearly never what you want. The official template linting rules [forbid usage of `{{unbound}}`](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/rule/no-unbound.md) as part of their recommended set.

`{{unbound pperson.medical.diseases '=' 0 'hidden'}}` is not a valid statement assuming that you haven't overloaded the default `{{unbound}}` template helper. I assume that you are missing something an `{{if}}` or `{{unless}}` condition in that snippet and a custom helper, which supports comparison with `pperson.medical.diseases '=' 0`.